# RESTful URL design for unauthenticated requests

Tags: rest, url-design

I want to provide the ability for resetting a user`s password. This call obviously must not require authentification.
First I thought of something like this:

`DELETE /users/{id}/password`: generates a reset token that gets sent to the user via email

`POST /users/{id}/password`: requires the new password and a valid reset token in the body

But the problem is, the application or website cannot provide me the ID of the user, because all it can ask the user for is his email address.

There are a number of other (unauthenticated) calls to our API, where the ID is not present and the user is only identified by its email.

We discussed the following solutions in our team:

- Replacing the ID in the URL with the users email
- Cut out the ID from the URL and provide the email with query parameters

If I had to choose between those two, I would take the first one, because I think it is not RESTful to provide something essential with query parameters, as they always represent something optional, like filtering a resource.
Are there better ways to design these URLs or is replacing the ID with the users email just fine concerning REST contraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
POST /passwordResets
{
    "emailAddress": "bob@example.com"
}
```

Then you have the flexibility to reset by userId also, and you can track the resets just like any other resource for auditing purposes.

Of your two options, the first isn't awful if you can use an email address to uniquely identify a user. It's conceptually wrong, though, because there should be one canonical location for each resource, and now you have two - `/users/bob/password` and `/users/bob@example.com/password`.

The second option is just wrong. `/users/password` is not meaningful. The direct implication of /users is that the next path element is a user. `/users/password` is closer to RPC than REST.